# What methods are used to negotiate between nodes about the features they support?

Tags: p2p, message

The version number that is exchanged when establishing a connection between nodes only indicates which features are potentially supported by the nodes (a feature that can be negotiated). In order to establish what they really support, some negotiation mechanism is needed. The two I know are:

1. via an additional message (sendcmpct, sendheaders, etc.)
2. via service flags

Are there any others?